# How to fetch the list of merge files along with other commits within a GIT branch using git log command?

Tags: git, github, git-log

How to fetch the list of merge files **along with other commits** within a GIT branch using git log command? For example, the sample command is given below,

**git log --after="11/29/2016" --before="11/20/2016"  --pretty='format:%cd %h' --name-status --date=short-local**

Comment: What do you mean by "merge files"? Note that `git log` finds and displays *commits*, and commits can be merge commits but such commits just contain "files" (like any other commit), not "merge files".

Comment: Merge files means the commits which has come through the merge (from other branches).

Answer (score 1):

From the comment:

> Merge files means the commits which has come through the merge (from other branches).

So, so you really want here is to find the commits that are *reachable* from the second through *n*'th parents of merge commit *M*, excluding all commits reachable from the first parent of *M*.

An ordinary merge commit has two parents `M^1` and `M^2` (this syntax is from [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)).  So if merge commit `M` has 99 parents, they are `M^1`, `M^2`, `M^3`, and so on all the way to `M^99`.  We use the `^` (hat or caret) character followed by a number *N*, written *after* any commit-specifier, to say "the *N*'th parent of that commit".  The commit-specifier is often just a raw hash (as from `git log` output): `face0ff`.

To *exclude* commits, we prefix them with the same `^` (hat or caret) character.  If `M` had those 99 parents, we would write `^M^1 M^2 M^3 M^4 ... M^99`.  But for the moment, we can just assume two parents and not have to count all the way to 99.

Hence, instead of `--since` and `--until` (aka `--after` and `--before`), we just need to find the hash ID of `M`—let's say it turns out to be `face0ff` after all—and run:

```
git log [options ...] ^face0ff^1 face0ff^2
```

(There is a special, more-general syntax that works even for Git's "octopus merges" like that 99-parent one: we write `M^@` to select all of them.  Then, to exclude the first one, we add `^M^1`.  It's OK to exclude one we already included: the exclusion winds up overriding.)

#### How and why this works

Given a series of commits (older commits on left, newer on right, and showing two of the branch-names in the repository, and I've given particularly-interesting commits letter names or `*` markings):

```
...--o--*--o---------X    <-- develop
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- feature
```

we will make a new merge commit on branch `develop` that brings in the five commits that are exclusive to branch `feature`:

```
...--o--*--o---------X--M   <-- develop
         \             /
          A--B--C--D--E     <-- feature
```

after which we may or may not make more commits on `develop`, and may even delete the branch *name* `feature`:

```
...--o--*--o---------X--M--o--o   <-- develop
         \             /
          A--B--C--D--E
```

The commits themselves—`A` through `E`—remain in the graph forever, protected (and reachable) by the name `develop`, since working backwards from `develop` we can find `M`, and `M` has *two* parents.

The first parent of any merge is always the commit that *was* the tip of the branch when we did the merge.  In this case, that's commit `X`, on the top line.  So we're not interested in the *first* parent after all; we want the *second* parent.<sup>1</sup>

Now, take note of commit `*`.  This is (obviously, from the visualization of the graph) the point at which the two sub-branches separate.  The particularly interesting thing about commit `*` is that *it's on **both** branches.*  This is true even *before* we make the merge commit.<sup>2</sup>  It remains true afterward, but *after* we make the commit, the merge causes commits `A` through `E` to be on branch `develop` as well!  That is, commits `*`-and-earlier were *always* on that branch, but commits `A-B-C-D-E` "joined up" once we made the merge.  They're now on *both* branches, just like commit `*` was before the merge.

If you like, you can think of commits—including merge commits—as stops on a rail line, with the peculiarity that the rails only run one way: from today towards the past.  If you board the train at the tip of `develop`, you have a choice when you reach rail-stop `M`: go "straight back" to `X`, or go "down and back" to `E`.  If you go to `E`, you will be able to reach rail-stops `D` through `A`, but if you go back to `X` you'll skip those stops.  No matter which way you go, though, if you *keep* going, you'll eventually arrive at rail-stop `*`.

The way `git log` works is to "travel the rails" from today back to the past, showing you each "rail stop" (commit) along the way.  When it reaches a fork like `M`, it takes *both routes* (and shows both of them to you, in some order<sup>3</sup>).  Eventually the forks rejoin (at commit `*`) and it can go back to showing you the stops along one route instead of two or more.

If, however, you tell `git log` to stop showing you certain commits, it will (of course) stop showing those commits.  Here's the tricky part: it stops not just those commits, but *all earlier ones too*.  So we use that.  We say: "As soon as you reach a commit that's either `M^1` itself *or* any commit *reachable from* `M^1`, stop traversing *that* history any further."

Hence, `^M^1` is an easy way to tell `git log`: "Don't show me commit `*`, or anything earlier."  Using `M^2` tells `git log`: "Do look from commit `M^2` when you go finding commits to show me."  We *don't* have to find commit `*` ourselves: we just have to realize that the chain starting from `M^1` eventually *reaches* `*`.

**This "reachability" idea is a key to understanding Git.**

---

<sup>1</sup>If this were an *octopus merge*—what Git calls any merge with three or more parents—we'd presumably want the additional parents too.

<sup>2</sup>This is a weird thing about Git.  In other version control systems (VCSes), when you *create* a branch, it gets some sort of distinctive uniqueness, and from then on, new commits made on that branch are only ever on that branch.  That remains true *even after you merge*, in those other VCSes: only commits made while on some particular branch, are ever on that branch; and those commits are *always* on that branch.  That's not true in Git, because in Git, we can move the branch *names* around, or even delete them entirely.  The commits themselves stay put, but the *names* change!

<sup>3</sup>You should immediately ask: *Wait, **what** order?*  The answer has to go elsewhere, though.  All I will say here is that the ordering is controlled by more options.